# Blank spaces in column names with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

One of the column names in my database is two words long, including a blank space, i.e.: `Area One`. I am using SELECT and referring to the column names to pull the data I want. Now if I name the column `_Area_One_`, my SELECT works, but if I use `_Area One_`, it does not. It says *Unknown column 'Area' in 'field list'*

Ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use backticks.

```
SELECT * FROM `Area One`
```

Comment: Correct.  Although this is definitely a very poor practice (I don't even let me developers use mixed-case -- perhaps I'm too stringent).

Comment: Mmm.. Does not work.. But maybe because of my setup.. This is the situation.. I have a db table.. users.. I have another table codes.. I have columns in the codes db, such as Zone, Area One, Area Two, Area Three etc.. On the page before I have the area (Area One, Area Two, Area Three etc) go into session.. session_area.. I also put Zone into session as session zone.. Different userid's are in the db.. So basically it is
Zone, Area One, Area Two, Area Three
0001, userid_23, userid_78, userid_99

Comment: Now I get that to work out the user id I need and then get the relevent records from the user db..

Comment: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = (select ".$_SESSION[`session_area`]." from zones WHERE zones='".$_SESSION['session_zones']."' limit 1)"

Comment: Now this all works fine if Session called Area_One but not Area One?