# php not creating mysql column correctly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to dynamically create tables in `MySQL`, using `CodeIgniter` PHP framework:

```
if($colname != ''){
            $str = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $colname (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), site_id INT NOT NULL, name BLOB NOT NULL)ENGINE=INNOBD;";
            $query = $this->db->query($str);
```

When I execute that from the `MySQL` command prompt, it created the table perfectly. However, if it's done through `CodeIgniter`, I'm getting the following error:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
        <p>Error Number: 1064</p><p>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tc 11' (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), site_id INT NOT NULL, ' at line 1</p><p>CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'tc 11' (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), site_id INT NOT NULL, name BLOB NOT NULL)ENGINE=INNOBD;</p>
```

What's going on here?
Thanks

Comment: try to print the value of `$colname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using quotes `'` and not backticks `` ` to surround your table name. MySQL uses [backticks to escape names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/using-backticks-around-field-names).

You should change the value of `$colname` from

```
'tc 11'
```

To this:

```
`tc 11`
```

You can do that with:

```
$colname = str_replace("'", "`", $colname);
```

Other resources that confirm this:

- [Blank spaces in column names with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055505/blank-spaces-in-column-names-with-mysql)

(Sorry about the code blocks; SO has an issue with backticks inside inline code)

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are passing an incorrect value in $colname

First i assume `$colname` is supposed to be `$tablename`, because this is a query to create a table.

and it seems like there is a space in your table name, please show what value you have in your $colname variable.

there should be no space, `TC_11`

Comment: then I need a regular expression to replace ' ' by '_' if in the middle of the string

Comment: @philippe MySQL will accept it with a space if you escape it properly with backticks

Comment: @philippe are you trying to create a table or a column?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Do you know a regular Expression that replaces ' ' by '_' if it the middle of the program, and trims it if it is in the beginning ...

Comment: I'm trying to create a table to represent a column in a `JavaScript` table.

Comment: @philippe You can use `str_replace()`. You don't need a regex. But you shouldn't have to worry about that. If you surround your table name in backticks, you won't have to change the spaces to underscores.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `".str_replace(' ','',$colname)."` (id...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your sql query. The following code should do the job and also make it safer.

```
if(!empty($colname))
{
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ? (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), site_id INT NOT NULL, name BLOB NOT NULL)ENGINE=INNOBD;";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($colname));
}
```